# Getting updated state right after state is updated right after dispatch within a component

Tags: reactjs, express, authentication, redux, redux-saga

I'm making login auth call from Redux Saga, so in JSX I can wait for the state to update using conditional rendering but how can I wait for it in for ex. `onSubmit` function so that I can redirect if login is successful.

I'm using conditional statements to check if the user is logged in or not within `onSubmit` function right after dispatching the `props.login(values)` but I get the older state that has `isLoggedIn` set to false.

Login Component

```
    <Formik
        initialValues={{
            email: '',
            password: '',
        }}
        validationSchema={LoginSchema}
        onSubmit={(
            values,
            { setSubmitting, resetForm },
        ) => {
            props.login(values);
            setTimeout(() => {
                if(props.isLoggedIn) {
                    props.history.push('/'); // Functional Component
                } else {
                    resetForm();
                }
                setSubmitting(false);
            }, 500);
       }}
    >
```

Initial State

```
const initialState = {
    currentUser: {},
    isLoggedIn: false,
    errors: '',
    propertyMessages: '',
};
```

Reducers

```
const rootReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case AUTH: {
            if (action.payload.error) {
                return {
                    ...state,
                    errors: action.payload.error,
                };
            } else {
                localStorage.setItem('access-token', action.payload);
                const user = jwtDecode(action.payload);
                return {
                    ...state,
                    errors: '',
                    isLoggedIn: true,
                    currentUser: {
                        id: user.id,
                        name: user.name,
                    },
                };
            }
        }
        case LOGOUT: {
            localStorage.removeItem('access-token');
            return {
                ...state,
                isLoggedIn: false,
                currentUser: {},
                errors: '',
            };
        }
        default:
            return state;
    }
};
```

Redux Saga

```
function* loginSaga(payload) {
    try {
        const data = yield call(loginCall, payload); // Get token
        yield put({ type: AUTH, payload: data });
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
}
```

The `isLoggedIn` sets to `true` right after the `props.login(values)` dispatches but since the logic for redirection is right after the dispatcher if get's called with old state.

Expected results will happen if the redirection logic can be put on delay or incase of conditional rendering the component renders and cause redirects since it will have the updated value.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
        if (this.props.currentUser !== prevProps.currentUser) {
            this.props.history.push('/');
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand your problem, you need to make props.login thenable i.e. a promise. Return a promise from the login function and put the if logic in `then` 
something like this. More about this can be told if you share your login code.

```
onSubmit={(
            values,
            { setSubmitting, resetForm },
        ) => {
            props.login(values)
              .then(() => {
                if(props.isLoggedIn) {
                    props.history.push('/'); // Functional Component
                } else {
                    resetForm();
                }
                setSubmitting(false);
              })
       }
      }
```